# Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green equivalent in PSCmdlet in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I'm writing a Cmdlet in C#.

At some points I want to have a colored output like PowerShell command:

```
Write-Host "Message" -ForegroundColor Green
```

My C# code is like this:

```
public class MyCmdlet : PSCmdlet
{
    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        // Something like: WriteHost("Message", Color.Green);
        // ...
    }
}
```

but the only options are `Write-Warning`, `Write-Error`, `Write-Object`, ...

So my question is:

**Question:** How can I put some lot on the output with colors?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`Host`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.management.automation.pscmdlet.host.aspx) property of `PSCmdlet` class to interact with host:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @‘
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "HostUIWrite")]
    public class TestHostUIWriteCmdlet : PSCmdlet {
        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            Host.UI.WriteLine(ConsoleColor.Green, Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor, "SomeText");
        }
    }
’@ -PassThru|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Assembly|Import-Module
Test-HostUIWrite
```

Also you could use `Write-Host` cmdlet from your code:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @‘
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    using Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands;
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "WriteHost")]
    public class TestWriteHostCmdlet : PSCmdlet {
        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            using(PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create(RunspaceMode.CurrentRunspace)) {
                ps.
                AddCommand(new CmdletInfo("Write-Host", typeof(WriteHostCommand))).
                AddParameter("Object", "SomeText").
                AddParameter("ForegroundColor", ConsoleColor.Yellow).
                Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
’@ -ReferencedAssemblies Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Utility -PassThru|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Assembly|Import-Module
Test-WriteHost
```

If you are targeting PowerShell v5, then you can use the `WriteInformation` method:

```
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @‘
    using System;
    using System.Management.Automation;
    [Cmdlet(VerbsDiagnostic.Test, "WriteInformation")]
    public class TestWriteInformationCmdlet : PSCmdlet {
        protected override void ProcessRecord() {
            WriteInformation(new HostInformationMessage { Message="SomeText",
                                                          ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Red,
                                                          BackgroundColor=Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor,
                                                          NoNewLine=false
                                                        }, new[] { "PSHOST" });
        }
    }
’@ -PassThru|Select-Object -ExpandProperty Assembly|Import-Module
Test-WriteInformation
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`System.Console`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) class has properties to set the colour:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
```

(Not a great combination of colours :-).)

The existing value is the current colour: save to restore.

---

Important: Other than `Write-Host` the other cmdlets do not assume they are writing to something that has colours – they could be redirected to a file. Additionally the possible values for `Write-Host`'s `ForegroundColor` and `BackgroundColor` are affected by which PSH host is in use. For example using the console properties you can modify how each colour is shown, but that is not possible in ISE.

Have you considered just invoking `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand`?

Comment: How `System.Console` relates to PSH? Besides, I want to use colors for each `Write-*` separately. Using your solution I should set `Console.ForegroundColor` for each `Write`.

Comment: Do you suggest any tutorial or documentation for using Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteHostCommand?

Comment: @mehrandvd [SO] Doesn't do tutorial recommendations (they age too quickly). But it shouldn't be hard to find examples of using one CmdLet from within another. And yes, to mix up the colours in console output you need to set those properties each time the colour needs to change (I usually write helpers to set colour, write, restore colour).

Comment: @mehrandvd FIrst hit on a search gives me [*How to Invoke a Cmdlet from Within a Cmdlet*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)